# Toggle button onclick in react

Tags: reactjs

I am making a table in react, where I want to change the edit button to save when I click on it. I have tried the below code, I know this isn't the correct way. Can anyone tell me what is the correct approach?

---

This is the edit button in render. It calls edit function when clicked.
dataProp contains the json data I am importing from a file.

```
 {this.state.dataProp.map((data, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="show-grid row category-row">
          <div className="col-md-8 text-left category" key={data.brandId}>
           <b>{data.categoryName}</b></div>
          <div className="col-md-4 text-right" >
          <button className="edit" ref="newText" onClick={() => 
            this.edit(index)}>{this.state.text}</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
 })}
```

---

```
class DisplayTable extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  text: "EDIT",
  newArray: [],
  dataProp: this.props.dataProp,
  productsEditList:[ ---->This is for toggling individual button 
    {
      id: 0,
      isEdit: false
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      isEdit: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isEdit: false
    }
  ]
}
this.edit = this.edit.bind(this);
this.save = this.save.bind(this);
}
edit(key) {
  this.state.productsEditList.map(keyy => {
  if (key == keyy.id) {
    keyy.isEdit:true
   }
  this.save(key);
 })
}
save(key) {
  if (!this.state.editing.key) {
   this.setState({
   text: 'SAVE',
   editing: false
   })
  }
 }
```

---

This code causes all the buttons change to save when I click on any one of them.
I do not understand how should I toggle individual buttons. 
[all buttons changes to save when I click on anyone of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM181.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the text of the button in a state and toggled it whenever my button is clicked.
Here is the code for button -

```
 <button className={this.state.text === "EDIT" ? "edit" : "save"} onClick={() =>this.edit}>{this.state.text}
 </button>
```

---

Here is code for toggling the button

```
 edit() {
    if (this.state.editing === false) {
        this.setState({
            text: 'SAVE',
            editing: true
        });
    }
    else {
        this.setState({
            text: 'EDIT',
            editing: false
        });
        if (this.state.changedSkus.length > 0) {
            this.props.edit_menu_items_api({ "changedSkus": this.state.changedSkus });
        }
    }
    this.render();
}
```